# Displaying data in a TextBox/TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Good evening, please help me deal with my eternal problem of displaying data when working with the database.
I will start with the fact that this is my training project, it is implemented on the MVVM pattern, in the form of models are classes that are tables in sql.

1. One of the models, for example:

```
public class Income
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual UsersData UsersData { get; set; }
 
        public decimal PIncome { get; set; }
    }
```

All the application work is performed in one window.
Next VM:

```
public class PersonalAccountViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Income> m_Incomes { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Income> Incomes
        {
            get => m_Incomes;
            set
            {
                m_Incomes = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Incomes");
            }
        }
 
        public PersonalAccountViewModel()
        {
            InitCommands();
            using (var context = new UserContext())
            {
                var result = context.Income.Where(u => u.UserId == 1);
                Incomes = new ObservableCollection<Income>(result);
            }
        }
 
        public ICommand AddUserCommand { get; set; }
 
        void InitCommands()
        {
            AddUserCommand = new RelayCommand(AddUser);
        }
 
        void AddUser()
        {
            using (var context = new UserContext())
            {
                    var income = new Income()
                    {
                        UserId = user.Id,
                        PIncome = 0
                    };
                    context.Income.Add(income);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
        }
```

And View

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Incomes.PIncome, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The problem is that the data is not displayed. The logic followed this: after creating the database in the constructor, information will be read(for example, for the first user (id == 1), the database is connected, linq is performed successfully, but the display is already a horseradish...
Help me solve this problem once and for all - I will be very grateful;

Comment: `Incomes.PIncome` is not a valid binding path. You should have observed data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug your application. How is your view supposed to visualize the `Incomes` collection? Where exactly is the TextBox declared, in an ItemTemplate perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new myself so I cannot comment on your question.
We need to see your view.  Have you set the DataContext of your view to the view model instance?

For example in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="...">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:PersonalAccountViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

Or in code behind, e.g. in the constructor of the Window:

```
public partial class MyView : Window
{
    private readonly PersonalAccountViewModel model = new PersonalAccountViewModel();

    public MyView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = model;
    }
}
```

Once you have set the DataContext your view can bind to your view model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not the problem. The relationship between view and viewModel is present